# What does <int(int)> mean in a function template?

Tags: c++11, templates

I know this is an easy question but I can't seem to find a specific answer anywhere!

Going through test code for threads in c++11, and don't understand the meaning of this template function statment:

```
packaged_task<int(int)> task1(&myComputation);
```

Not sure what 'int(int)' means in this code. I understand in general that what is passed into the brackets < > is the type of what is being passed to the template definition.  Is this some sort of type casting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In this context, the int(int) represents the type signature of a function pointer to a function that takes one parameter (an int), and returns an int. So, if I were to write:

```
int myFunction(int value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

std::packaged_task<int(int)> myPackagedTask{&myFunction};
```

the packaged_task would now contain a function pointer to myFunction. Following, this would be an error:

```
int mySecondFunction(int value, int secondValue) {
    std::cout << value << " : " << secondValue << std::endl;
}
std::packaged_task<int(int)> myPackagedTask{&mySecondFunction}; //compile error, mySecondFunction does not match signature int(int)
```

Comment: Thank you! So in general, the parantheses part () is the type of the returned value?

Comment: No problem! The parentheses part actually represents the arguments to the function, and the parameter outside of the parentheses represents the functions return type. So, for functions that don't return anything, it is common to see that template parameter be <void(int)> (the function takes one int argument and returns void).